# Array of pointers in C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, parallel-processing

How do I create a *array containing multiple pointers* in C?

**e.g.** If you have a data-set of size `n` which you want to split into `t` chunks. So if you want to access an element in the range `0-(n/t)` , you would need to access the array index and go to the corresponding pointer index.

Comment: I think you need to clarify ... "pointers of varying length" doesn't make sense, and you mention arrays in the title but not in the actual text.

Comment: So I made some clarification to the question. In essence want to split some content and make it easily accessible through an 'outer' index, and then being able to pass a single pointer on to a sorting method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work for `int` data

```
int *arr_of_ptr[t];
for(int i = 0; i < t; i++)
    arr_of_ptr[i] = malloc(sizeof(int) * n/t);
```

Answer (score 0):

So you want to store `n` elements in `t` arrays. 
First note that `n` modulo `t` may not be 0. So you can't simply store `n/t` elements in the `t` arrays.

You'll want to store `m = n / (t-1)` elements in the `t-1` first arrays and the rest in the last array.

```
int i, m;

// Create an array of t arrays that will contain the value of type T
T **arrays = malloc(t*sizeof(T*));

// Compute the maximum number of elements in each array 
m = n / (t-1);

// Create the t arrays
for (i = 0; i < t; ++i)
    arrays[i] = malloc(m*sizeof(T));
```

To access the element `k` in this data structure, you have to determine the index `i` of the array holding the data, and the index `j` of the element in the array.  The index `i` is `i = k/m`, and the index `j` is `j = k%m` (k modulo m).

The following expression thus gives you access to the element k of the n elements.

```
arrays[k/m][k%m]
```